# How to post email message in Slack channel from specific sender?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'd like to set up an integration such that any email coming from a particular sender would get posted in a specific Slack channel and is able to be viewed by all members of that particular channel.  It's possible that the members of this Slack channel will also get the same email so having an integration that will fire for every user in the channel would NOT be ideal since that would result in multiple posts of the same message in Slack.

What type of integration/app/webhook could help achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is 100% what you're looking for but you should definitely give [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai/help/send-email-to-slack) a try. You'll be able to receive emails in Slack and sort your emails depending on the sender. To know how to do so, have a look to the tip: [Receive alerts in separate channels](https://mailclark.ai/help/pro-tips#alerts). Let me know if I can help!